# How do I display place labels instead of A or B in Google Maps directions API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to display names of the places on the map instead of labels A and B. How do I do it in Google Maps Directions API? For example, just `Start` and `End` or `Miami Port` to `Miami Tower`.

**`CODE`**

```
    let directionsDisplay;
    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    let map;

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    let myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    let mapArea = document.getElementById("map_canvas_track_order");

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapArea, myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    let start = `25.757928, -80.192897`;
    let end = `25.771969, -80.191235`;
    let request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
```

**`CURRENT MAP PREVIEW`**

[image: Map Preview]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can hide default Marker `A` and `B` using `suppressMarkers` property as `true`.

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map, suppressMarkers: true});
```

And then Make your own Marker at the end points using `Marker`.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: ,
                label: "~what you want~",
                map: map
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to suppress the markers. What would be the value of  `position`? I'm thinking `position: 'A'`? Also, where exactly do I implement the created marker?

Comment: Position is {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044} see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple